# Azure Devops The BaseOutputPath/OutputPath property is not set for project

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild

I read enough about 'Any CPU' for solution builds and 'AnyCPU' for project builds, in my case both fail.

Using a fresh .Net Framework (4.7.2) web project fails to build. I've tried windows-latest (2022) and windows-2019 bothnwith the same error. Tried both Release and Debug.

Yes, the project has Debug|AnyCPU and Release|AnyCPU configurations. Doesn't matter if I try to build the solution or the project directly. It fails

```
##[error]C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(824,5): Error : The BaseOutputPath/OutputPath property is not set for project 'Test.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Debug'  Platform='AnyCPU'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project.
```

Yaml step is pretty simple

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2022'

variables:
  solution: 'Test.sln'
  project: 'Test.csproj'
  buildPlatform: 'AnyCPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\$(solution)'
    platform: 'Any CPU'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    clean: true


- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build projects'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\$(projectFolder)\$(project)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    clean: true
```

In the above, the project build never executes as the solution build fails. If I remove the solution build the project build fails. all with the same error.

The project is as I said, a fresh/clean web project. So no idea what I've got wrong. I've had this working in other projects... but I just can't see what I've set incorrectly.

```
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{24EB16C1-0008-4C24-9EED-26C862910287}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>WebApplication1</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>WebApplication1</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
    <Use64BitIISExpress />
    <IISExpressSSLPort>44372</IISExpressSSLPort>
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
    <UseGlobalApplicationHostFile />
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
    <Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.2\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Http">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Http.WebHost">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Global.asax" />
    <Content Include="Web.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Global.asax.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Global.asax</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="packages.config" />
    <None Include="Web.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="Web.Release.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="App_Data\" />
    <Folder Include="Controllers\" />
    <Folder Include="Models\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>6036</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>https://localhost:44372/</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props'))" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: I assume building the Solution fails because you're setting `platform'` to `'Any CPU'` instead of `'AnyCPU'`

Comment: @cdmdotnet Did you figure it out?

Comment: I posted my personal solution for this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77157578/7088393). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was caused by an **Assembly Info (.Net Core & .Net Standard)** (`Assembly-Info-NetCore@3`) build task manipulating and re-ordering the XML of some .NET framework csproj files.

Setting `IgnoreNetFrameworkProjects: true` fixed the build most of the projects, except my Xamarin ios csproj, which was not detected as a .NET Framework project, so I had to exclude that file explicilty.

`Assembly-Info-NetCore@3` does appear process the file as XML, so sections of csproj do get reordered significantly.