# BaseOutputPath/OutputPath property is not set for project '.sfproj'

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops, devops

I created Service Fabric project targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2. Building locally works fine and the Swagger page is loading.

It is failing to build in Azure DevOps and I do not understand why. The error is-

```
BaseOutputPath/OutputPath property is not set for project 'Test.sfproj'.

Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid 
combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.
  Configuration='Release'
  Platform='x64'.

You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build
a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default
Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a lot of different possible causes to this problem. In our case, the problem was in the `.sfproj` file: the tag `<SupportedMSBuildNuGetPackageVersion>1.7.9</SupportedMSBuildNuGetPackageVersion>` was referencing a version of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild` too high for our Service Fabric version (which is lagging behind two major versions. It worked once we downgraded to version 1.7.6 in that specific tag.